# Kendo Angular ContextMenu not showing onShow="click"

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, contextmenu

Hy,

I have a problem with Kendo Angular context menu. I would like that context menu would show on click, not right click.

So I set

> k-show-on="click",

in the attributes of the kendo-angular directive (found this setting in docs on 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu#configuration-showOn )

But it doesn't work. Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/uLaSE/3

Same with direction - if I set direction:"left" it still appers on the right side. Same example, first context menu.

Any idea? Is this feature disabled in Kendo-Angular?

Tnx for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
k-show-on="'click'"
```

Click event is a string and not scope variable so it should be in quotation marks.